# Implement a calendar app with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Does Codename One offer APIs to show a month calendar and select a day in that monthly view?

I’d like to implement a calendar with basic features, like add notes and recurring events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both the `Calendar` class (in the UI package which is historically badly named) and the `Picker` class support this. There is also a calendar library which allows you to insert/list events from the underlying native calendar although I'm not sure what's the status of that cn1lib.